# Test Class - VF Controller that creates a report link - Test Fails

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, reports-api

I updated my hard coded link in a visualforce page that references a report with a SOQL query in the controller. It works great except when I try and run the test class. I can't tell for sure but it looks like the test class can't see the report even though my test user is a full system admin.

Report is in a shared folder and I even added the "All Internal Users" group to the folder to make sure it could be seen.

Is there a way around this or do you have to create a report in the @testsetup node? If so, what is the syntax? I tried but I got an error that both Name and DeveloperName on report are not writeable.

Here are some code snippets from controller:

```
    public with sharing class Admin_Tracking_Controller {
    public      report              reportId            {get;set;}

    public Admin_Tracking_Controller() {
        reportId                    = [SELECT Id,Name 
                                       FROM Report
                                       USING SCOPE everything
                                       WHERE DeveloperName = 'My_Tracker_Log'];
and so on....
}
}
```

Visualforce page link:

```
<apex:outputLink target="_blank" 
                 style="color:white;" 
                 value="/{!reportId.Id}" 
                 id="theLink">
    My Tracker Log
</apex:outputLink>
```

Thanks,

Comment: IIRC Reports are isolated from test methods and you will need to create an instance of a report in your test methods. If that is not possible you will have to restructure your class to use a mock report record

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to this issue is to use the Separation of Concerns pattern such as found in the Force.com Enterprise Architecture book by Andy Fawcett and corresponding [open source GITHUB lib](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common-samplecode): `fflib`. But, this isn't a trivial undertaking

But, you can approximate the pattern in this limited use case

In your controller:

```
public interface IReportsSelector {
    Report selectByDevName(String devName);
}

@TestVisible IReportsSelector reportsSelector = new ReportsSelectorImpl();

public ID reportId {
     get { return reportsSelector.selectByDevName('My_Tracker_Log');}
     private set;
}
public Admin_Tracking_Controller() {
    // don't fetch Report in constructor, use a getter
    ...
}

// Your PROD selector layer implementation 
public class ReportsSelectorImpl implements IReportsSelector {
   Report selectByDevName(String devName) {
     return [select Id, Name from Report where DeveloperName = :devName];
}
```

In your test class, you will provide a mock implementation of the SOQL query and tell the PROD class to use that mock at runtime during the testmethod

The mock implementation uses `Json.deserialize` to create an sobject that is returned by your selector layer.  `Json.deserialize` can create sobjects otherwise unmockable through normal Apex sobject operations or by DML.

```
@isTest private class MyTestClass {
   // Your mock selector implementation
   public class ReportsSelectorMock implements MyController.IReportsSelector {
     public Report selectByDevName(String devName) {
        return (Report) Json.deserialize(
                          '{"ID": "00O000000000000",' +
                          ' "DeveloperName": "' + devName + '"}',
                          Report.class);         

   }
  @isTest private static myTest () {
     Admin_Tracking_Controller controller = new Admin_Tracking_Controller();
     controller.reportsSelector = new ReportsSelectorMock(); // set mock
     System.assertNotEquals(null,controller.reportId); // verify
     .. other asserts   
  }
}
```

Now, admittedly, the above is overkill if all your controller needs is the `Report.Id` field - you can use the getter I defined above and a `Test.isRunningTest()` method to provide a mocked value - or, use the TestVisible annotation to inject an expected ID value. But it is worth knowing the Json.deserialize approach to sobject mocking